# Create django model instances from dataframe without server timeout

Tags: python, django, pandas, memory

I am uploading a zipped file that contains a single CSV file. I then unzip it on the server and load it into a dataframe. Then I am creating django objects from it.

This works fine until my dataframe becomes too large. When the dataset is getting too large the django server shuts down. I am assuming that this happens because every iteration in my loop increases memory and when there is no memory space left it shuts down. I am working with big datasets and want to make my code work no matter how big the dataframe.

Imagine I have a df like this:

```
                       cola   fanta   sprite   libella
2018-01-01 00:00:00    0        12      12       34
2018-01-01 01:00:00    1        34      23       23 
2018-01-01 02:00:00    2         4       2        4 
2018-01-01 03:00:00    3        24       2        4 
2018-01-01 04:00:00    4         2       2        5
```

Imagine that the columns could be up to 1000 brands and the rows could be more than half a Million rows. Further imagine I have a model that saves this data in a JSONB field. Thus every column is a django object, the column name being the name. The time-stamp combined with the data in the column is the JSONB field.

e.g.: `name=fanta, json_data={ "2018-01-01 00:00:00": 12, "2018-01-01 01:00:0": 34 }`

My code to unzip, load to df and then create a django instance is this:

```
        df = pd.read_csv(
            file_decompressed.open(name_file),
            index_col=0,
        )
        for column_name in df:
            Drink.objects.create(
                name=column_name,
                json_data=df[column_name].to_dict(),
            )
```

As I said, this works, but my loop breaks after having created about 15 elements. Searching the internet I found that `bulk_create` could make this more efficient. But I have custom signals implemented, so this is not really a solution. I also thought about using `to_sql`, but since I have to restructure the data of the dataframe I don't think this will work. Maybe not using pandas at all? Maybe chunking the DF somehow?

I am looking for a solution that works independently of the number of columns. Number of rows is maximum of half a million rows. I also tried a while-loop but same problem occurs.

Any ideas how I can make this work? Help is very much appreciated.

My dummy model could be as simple as:

```
class Juice(models.Model):
   name = CharField(...)
   json_data = JSONField(...)
```

Comment: Use [`Django Q`](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to process a long task.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Will this be more memory efficient?

Comment: Probably. Your script will not stop after any timeout.